# eclipse prevent the tab key from focusing on proposal table

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, key, settings

As soon as i removed my projects from eclipse workspace, when i try to autocomplete a method using the tab key, it just iterates or focuses on the method description that pops up.
they say "press tab from proposal table" so it's interfering with my already binded tab to auto complete.
I want to either remove this method explanation thing or change its key, i just want to be able to auto complete using tab key again. How can i do that?

[Here's an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIAgp.png)